# Problem connecting phone to PA/monitor

Tags: amplifiers, wiring, cable

I recently bought Alesis Strike Amp 12 for my E-drums and I having a real hard time when I want to connect my phone to it - I have no idea what cable to use.

Whenever I want to connect my phone using a TRS 1/8 jack connected to my phone and a 1/8 to 1/4 TRS adapter jack connected to the AMP, I have a terrible sound - I don't really know how to desribe it, but for example I almost don't hear the vocals - I'm not a technical kind of person, but I guess some channels in the cable are connected together when they shouldn't be.

If I do the same thing, but using a TS guitar cable (with 1/4 to 1/8 adapter to connect to phone) the sound is good.

My dad made me a cable that's standard 1/8 jack to connect to phone and a 1/4 TRS jack to amp that only has 1 channel connected to Tip and ground to sleeve - ring totally disconnected and it works OK.

So I'm wordering whether I should just use a TS mono cable or what, as the specs and manual included to the AMP says, that sockets for jacks on the amp accept TRS cables.
Sorry, if my description is not clear, but I'm not a technical person and I'm not a native English speaker.

Thank You in advance!

Comment: Is there an input on the brain of the drumkit that's there for the purpose?

Comment: Yes, I have an imput there and it works good when I connect my phone there, but I mean in a situation I want to use it just as a speaker for music from my phone, not when playing drums. All in all, it's still a PA that doesn't need drums to work properly, I guess.

Comment: A phone probably wants a TRRS jack, as it's expecting to see a stereo headset with mic.

Comment: I don't think that's the case, as when I connect my PC to it, the problem persists.

Comment: For the same reason - a TRS plug in a TRRS socket is going to knock one side out of phase… precisely the reason your vocals are disappearing.

Answer (score 1):

With two independent inputs, you need a stereo 1/8" jack from phone, split into two 1/4" TS jacks, one wired tip to tip, other wired tip to sleeve of 1/8" jack. That splits the signal in two, one for each channel. It says XLR/TRS socket, which those sockets are designed for. They're great, but have many different wiring capabilities. Possibly they're wired TRS - best person to ask is someone at Alesis - they're very approachable and knowledgable so call them.

Whatever happens, you obviously won't get stereo out of the 12" speaker, but you'll get a mono mix.The usual 1/8" jack for phones has an extra ring, for mic, which is redundant here, but check which ring is functioning as one side of the stereo out - a headphone set should tell either way.

Comment: Thank You, that was very helpful. I guess It'll be a good idea to contact Alesis directly just to make things clear once for good.